# difference between v1 and v2 of Erik's css-reset

Tags: css

I am comparing the difference between Erik's css reset at https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html

I notice that v2 doesn't reset `outline`, `background`. Why?

Comment: Not into following links. Update question

Comment: Whats wrong with giving a link?

Comment: Links die. This sounds like a question you should be asking "Erik"

Comment: @ManuChadha what happens when the content at the link changes?  Your question will lose all value it might have had.

Comment: Also you should do the most to make it easy for others to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search tells me that in the past developers liked to reset the outline style in order to remove the focus box on buttons and links [[link1]](http://www.outlinenone.com/)[[link2]](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/28/stop-messing-with-the-browsers-default-focus-outline/).

This can ruin the experience for people navigating with a keyboard (tabing through links) or impaired users (i.e. the partially blind). I assume the same reasoning applies to the background style.

It seems like a best practice now.